# FontAwesomeIcon is not changing color in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, svg, frontend, icons, react-font-awesome

All my dependencies are rightly installed, but still FontAwesomeIcon color is not changing to white or any other color. This is the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzd0P.png)

Comment: Please paste your code, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<FontAwesomeIcon
  icon={faBars}
  color='#FFF'
/>
```

Some context
https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome/pull/99

CodeSandbox example
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-northcutt-w65vx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-northcutt-w65vx?file=/src/App.js